# string was not recognized a valid DataTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm getting the error: "string was not recognized a valid Data Time"

```
SqlDataAdapter DataAp = new SqlDataAdapter(createCommand);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("User");

var user = new User();

TimeSpan timeSpanDays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(user.RegistrationTime.ToString()));
var days = timeSpanDays.Days;

if (days < 10)
{
     DataAp.Fill(dt);
     dgRecent.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
     DataAp.Update(dt);
}
```

Comment: -1. Where are you getting this error? What have you done to try to correct the code? Please give more details.

Comment: What exactly is `user.RegistrationTime` ? and what is `user.RegistrationTime.ToString()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In that case I guess your `user.RegistrationTime` is not a valid Date Time format... you could maybe use `parseExact()` instead of the simple `parse()` and specify the format if it's not a standard one.

Comment: ok, the format RegistrationTime is in is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. So how could I go about converting this?

Answer (score 0):

from your comments :
if RegistrationTime format is : `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

This :

```
TimeSpan timeSpanDays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(user.RegistrationTime.ToString()));
```

Should be:

```
TimeSpan timeSpanDays = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.ParseExact(user.RegistrationTime.ToString(),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Assuming Hours is 24 hour format.
Please let me know if you need anything more.